# Grails rejected value, type mismatch

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I don't know what's wrong with my code, the value is right but when I save it, it get errors

```
grails.validation.ValidationException: Validation Error(s) occured during save():
- Field error in object 'specialRate' on field 'fromCurrency': rejected value [IDR - Indonesian Rupiah]; codes [typeMismatch.specialRate.fromCurrency, ......

grails.validation.ValidationException: Validation Error(s) occured during save():
- Field error in object 'specialRate' on field 'validThru': rejected value [Mon JUl 15 00:00:00 ICT 2013]; codes [typeMismatch.specialRate.fromCurrency, ...... could not parse date: Unparsable date: "15/07/2013"]
```

here is my domain class

```
import java.util.Date;
import Currency;

    class SpecialRate {

        static auditable = true

            String bookingCode
        Currency fromCurrency
        Date validThru

        static constraints = {
        bookingCode(blank: false, maxSize :20)
            fromCurrency(blank:true, nullable: true)
            validThru(blank: true, nullable: true)      
        }
    }
```

here's the save controller:

```
def save = {    
        def specialRateInstance = new SpecialRate()
        specialRateInstance.properties = params
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
        specialRateInstance.validThru = formatter.parse(params.validThru)

        def fromCurrency = Currency.get(params.fromCurrency);
        specialRateInstance.fromCurrency = fromCurrency


        withFormat {
            html {
                withForm {
                    try {
                        specialRateInstance = specialRateService.save(specialRateInstance)
                    }
                    catch (grails.validation.ValidationException e) {
                        logger.error("Missing property or validation fails", e)
                    }
                    catch (RuntimeException e) {
                        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e)
                        redirect(controller: "error", action: "serverError")
                        return
                    }

                    if (!specialRateInstance.hasErrors()) {
                        flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'specialRate.label', default: 'SpecialRate'), specialRateInstance.bookingCode])}"
                        redirect(action: "show", id: specialRateInstance.id)
                    }
                    else {
                        render(view: "create", model: [specialRateInstance: specialRateInstance ])
                    }
                }.invalidToken {
                    redirect(controller: "error", action: "forbidden")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and the service :

```
def save (def specialRateInstance){
        specialRateInstance.save(failOnError: true)
        return specialRateInstance
    }
```

anyone can help me and found my mistake, so my code get error results?
thanks :)

Comment: Did you try just: `def specialRateInstance = new SpecialRate(params)`

Answer (score 0):

- `fromCurrency` is of type `Currency` but you would be setting a string value from `params`.
- `validThru` is unparseable because the format is `Mon JUl 15 00:00:00 ICT 2013` and you are expecting it to be `dd/MM/yyyy`.

*Steps to recover:-*

- Follow @James Kleeh.
- Verify `fromCurrency` to be of type `Currency` once set.
- Match the date format for `validThru`. Make sure `validThru` is set in `params` as `dd/MM/yyyy`.